# Botones con funcionalidades Django

Tags: html, django, django-views

Se como hacer que un enlace ejecute una accion en particular: se la envia a la url pertinente y esta activa la funcion asociada, el problema es que resulta fastidioso tener que convertir una url en un boton bonito por medio de css, para que no luzca como un vulgar enlace azul subrayado. Quiero saber si hay una manera de usar los botones normales de html, los input de toda la vida, para q activen las funciones views.py de Django.

Osea no tener que poner un:

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Salir</a>
```

En el html.

Comment: Ambas, los **button** y las etiquetas **a** se les pueden modificar el diseño con **CSS**, y darle el estilo que más queramos.           Y para un enlace, se pueden combinar: un *button* dentro de una etiqueta *a*.

Comment: soy nuevo, pero estuve investigando y encontré esto, a ver si te funciona https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/django-how-to-add-multiple-submit-button-in-single-form/amp/

Answer (score -1):

Creo que la forma mas sencilla de hacer esto es poner un boton entre la etiqueta del enlace, de la siguiente forma:

```
  <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">
      <button>Salir</button>
  </a>
```